# Biblatex urldate set to today

Tags: biblatex, biber, datetime

When writing a document I want the `urldate` (the date of visit) of online bibliographical entries set to the day of compilation. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@online{abc,
title = {This is a Title},
author = {Author, Some},
url = {http://www.somesite.com},
date = {2013-10-10},
urldate = {\year-\month-\day} % this does not work. Also urldate = {\today} doesn't.
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{abc}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The hypthens are in the text because `biblatex` expect dates to be in the form of `yyyy-mm-dd`. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Surely the `urldate` should be the date the page was visited. If the page has changed in the meantime, it might be that the text you quote on the page (which was there when you visited the page last week) is no longer there. So surely you want the `urldate` to pick out a date when it really was the case that the quote was at that location... Setting the `urldate` to today's date makes the field completely useless.

Comment: I agree with @Seamus, but nonetheless a conceptually interesting question (with a proper MWE), so +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
       \pertype{online}
       \step[fieldset=urldate,fieldvalue={\the\year-\the\month-\the\day}]
    } 
 }
}
```

This definition overwrites every `urldate` field of the type online and used the current date.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@online{abc,
title = {This is a Title},
author = {Author, Some},
url = {http://www.somesite.com},
date = {2013-10-10},
urldate = {xxxx} % this does not work. Also urldate = {\today} doesn't.
}
\end{filecontents}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
       \pertype{online}
       \step[fieldset=urldate,fieldvalue={\the\year-\the\month-\the\day}]
    } 
 }
}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{abc}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I would like to do this for some articles (mine) but not for all. Is this possible as well?

Answer (score 3):

Not exacty what you asked for, but perhaps a compromise of sorts, taking into consideration [@Seamus’ comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149506/biblatex-urldate-set-to-today#comment339915_149506). I store a specific date (if you want, today) in a string and refer to that string in the single entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@string{today = {2013-12-11}}

@online{abc,
title = {This is a Title},
author = {Author, Some},
url = {http://www.somesite.com},
date = {2013-10-10},
urldate = today,
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{abc}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is the way I used to deal with the situation, but I thought there could be a better solution hence the question.